# libGDX 3D following and facing object

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I have a two Model Instances `modelInstance1` and `modelInstance2`.

```
modelInstance1 - position Vector3(0,0,0)
modelInstance2 - position Vector3(10,10,10)
```

How can I do Rotate modelInstance1 to modelInstance2 and move this direction in update method?

Question after answer:

I am tried aply answer to basic xoppa's cube tutorial and something is bad. What is wrong please?

```
@Override
public void create() {
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 10f, 
        new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
        Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);

    instance1 = new ModelInstance(model);
    instance2 = new ModelInstance(model);

    instance2.transform.translate(10,0,10);

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
}
```

Render and Update method.

```
@Override
public void render() {

    Vector3 position1 = new Vector3(), position2 = new Vector3(), direction = new Vector3();

    instance1.transform.getTranslation(position1);
    instance2.transform.getTranslation(position2);
    direction = (position2).sub(position1).nor();

    instance1.transform.setToRotation(direction, Vector3.X);

instance2.transform.translate(0.05f, 0, 0.05f).rotate(0, 1, 0, 10*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()).translate(0, 0, 0);


    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance1, environment);
    modelBatch.render(instance2, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

I tried change setToRotate method to:

```
instance1.transform.setToLookAt(position1, position2, new Vector3(0,1,0));
```

but same problem..

Comment: what are your constraints on "following"?

Comment: Rotate modelInstance1 to modelInstance2 and move this direction.

Comment: have you tried to multiply the matrix of the first modelInstance by the lookAtMatrix that points to the second?

Comment: Nope, could you post simple example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Facing to* in pseudo-code looks like:

```
modelInstance1.direction(from matrix) = (modelInstance2.position).sub(modelInstance1.position).nor();
modelInstance1.setRotation(modelInstance1.direction, Vector3.Y);
```

Update:
in this example direction vector is applied on Vector3.Y axis of the object. Hovewer your scene could have another axis system, so sometimes you need to try different object's axises to find target axis.

Comment: I changed a post, could you tell me what is wrong please?

Comment: *instance2.transform.translate* should be before *direction* calculation (if expected instance1 looks on instance2). And this is only *Facing to* part.

Comment: Ok, and how to do instance1 everytime looking on moving  instance2?

Comment: Code you're using should be enough, hovewer you could experiment with parameters in:
instance1.transform.setToRotation(direction, Vector3.X or Vector3.Y or Vector3.Z);
What is the actual output you've got?

Comment: I tried change Vector3.X and I thing that inst1 need to reverse becouse It's rotating on second side than it would rotate. Instance2 go to right and instance1 rotate to left.

Comment: I could suggest 2 variants:
1) you already have direction vector, so after it calculated: direction.set(-direction.x, -direction.y, -direction.z)
2) or instance1.transform.setToRotation(direction, new Vector(-1,0,0) OR new Vector(0,-1,0) OR new Vector(0,0,-1));

Answer (score 0):

Finally....that's it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

When somebody know how same code do better let me know please.

I hope that help to somebody else. :)

```
    Vector3 position1 = new Vector3(), position2 = new Vector3(), direction = new Vector3();

    instance2.transform.translate(0.5f, 0, 0.5f).rotate(0, 1, 0, 45*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()).translate(0, 0, 0);

    instance1.transform.getTranslation(position1);
    instance2.transform.getTranslation(position2);
    direction = (position2).sub(position1).nor();

    direction.set(-direction.x, -direction.y, -direction.z);

    Quaternion quaternion = new Quaternion();
    Matrix4 instanceRotation = instance1.transform.cpy().mul(instance1transform);

    instanceRotation.setToLookAt(direction, new Vector3(0,-1,0));
    instanceRotation.rotate(0, 0, 1, 180);
    instanceRotation.getRotation(quaternion);

    instance1.transform.set(position1, quaternion);
```